# Swift Spell Check Algorithm

Tags: swift, algorithm, function, spell-checking

Stuck trying to make a function that can spell check without using built in UITextChecker. I'd like to assume something like 'ce3t' as 'cat'.

Only help I could find online:
https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/05/02/spelling/

but that is for swiftc and doesn't even work.

Comment: The referenced code *is* Swift (swiftc is the Swift compiler). How does it “not work”? Of course it is an older version of Swift and needs to be adjusted for Swift 4.

Comment: @MartinR I am seeing errors in xcode like Use of unresolved identifier 'indices'...'dropFirst'...'map'